# Filter an array returns empty

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to populate an array with all values retrieved (I am in a loop) and then to delete values already present in the yearsJustSelected array:

```
yearsJustSelected.forEach((el:any)=>{
    yearsJustSelectedAll.push(el);
  });


  yearsJustSelectedFiltered = yearsJustSelected.filter((el: any) => !yearsJustSelectedAll.includes(el));
```

For example:
loop 1 --> yearsJustSelected=[1, 2, 3] - yearsJustSelectedAll=[1, 2, 3] - yearsJustSelectedFiltered = []
loop 2 --> yearsJustSelected=[2, 3, 4, 5] - yearsJustSelectedAll=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] - yearsJustSelectedFiltered=[4, 5] --> because [2, 3 ] were already present in the yearsJustSelectedAll in the first loop

This code:

```
yearsJustSelectedFiltered = yearsJustSelected.filter((el: any) => !yearsJustSelectedAll.includes(el));
```

always return an empty array.

Comment: Your `.forEach()` adds every value from `yearsJustSelected` into `yearsJustSelectedAll`, so there doesn't seem to be any case where 
 your filter condition (`!yearsJustSelectedAll.includes(el)`) would be `true`...

Comment: Your filter is saying “loop over the elements of the array and remove any that aren’t elements of the array”. They are **all** elements of the array...that’s why they show up as your filter iterates over them.

Comment: Sorry about that; you are right... I need a pause!

Answer (score 0):

```
  yearsJustSelected.forEach((el:any)=>{
    yearsJustSelectedAll.push(el);
  });
// The code above will add all elements in yearsJustSelected into yearsJustSelectedAll
// making the two arrays the same.

There are no instances where one array has elements that are not in the other array
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the target array does not have the item. Then push the item to the target array.

```js
function select(source, target) {
    source.forEach(v => target.includes(v) || target.push(v));
}

var yearsJustSelectedAll = [];

select([1, 2, 3], yearsJustSelectedAll);
console.log(...yearsJustSelectedAll);

select([2, 3, 4, 5], yearsJustSelectedAll);
console.log(...yearsJustSelectedAll);

select([4, 5], yearsJustSelectedAll);
console.log(...yearsJustSelectedAll);
```